# How to lock memory from unprivileged user?

Tags: memory, locking, solaris

I need to lock pages of my program in memory. 
Program run under Solaris 10 OS from unprivileged user. 
I've tried to use: mlock(), mlockall() and plock(), but always get the same result:

plock/mlock/mlockall: Not owner

But it works from root. So can I lock pages of my program in memory from unprivileged user, somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found decision and want to share it. May be it will be helpful for someone else.
I modified privileges of user, under Solaris it can be done by next command:

```
usermod -K defaultpriv=basic,proc_lock_memory user
```

I think in Linux could be the same situation and it can be resolved using Linux capabilities.